# Show Google Interstitial Ad On Button Click In site on WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I made a WebView application with my site for generating images. Also i added in Android Studio Google AdMob ad (banner and interstitial) with banner everything is fine and interstitial ad opens on application start as i put it in onCreate (i don't know other options) but i would like to make interstitial ad pop up after 10-20 clicks on the generate button, the problem is that it is on the site in a WebView and I am very weak in programming, please help, I have been struggling with this issue for a long time ,_, Any suggestions are welcome thanks.

I reviewed a lot of videos and publications, it seems to me that (WebView.addJavascriptInterface) would help me, but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can show ads by tracking WebView click.

First, add these two

```
int triggerClicks = 5;
int countClicks = 0;
```

add this listener for webView

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public final static int FINGER_RELEASED = 0;
        public final static int FINGER_TOUCHED = 1;
        public final static int FINGER_DRAGGING = 2;
        public final static int FINGER_UNDEFINED = 3;

        private int fingerState = FINGER_RELEASED;


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (fingerState == FINGER_RELEASED) fingerState = FINGER_TOUCHED;
                    else fingerState = FINGER_UNDEFINED;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(fingerState != FINGER_DRAGGING) {
                        fingerState = FINGER_RELEASED;

                        // Click count
                       clickCount();           

                    }
                    else if (fingerState == FINGER_DRAGGING) fingerState = FINGER_RELEASED;
                    else fingerState = FINGER_UNDEFINED;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (fingerState == FINGER_TOUCHED || fingerState == FINGER_DRAGGING) fingerState = FINGER_DRAGGING;
                    else fingerState = FINGER_UNDEFINED;
                    break;

                default:
                    fingerState = FINGER_UNDEFINED;

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Control clicks and show ads

```
    public void clickCount() {

    // Count
    countClicks++;

    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded() && countClicks >= triggerClicks) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        // Reset clicks again
        countClicks = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! As far as I understand, this code will allow showing ads after clicks anywhere? Is it possible to make it count only clicks on a specific button in the webview?